# bootstrap jquery datatable clear before loading and

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using jquery bootstrap style **datatable**. I have 3 input fields and one search button in screen and when I am hitting search button first time without any input I am getting correct result(suppose 1000 records) with pagination

But when next time I am hitting search button with some input I am getting the below error **table id can not reinitilize Datatable for more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3**. and I am getting the result(suppose 200 records) but the pagination is showing for the fist search(1000 records).

Below is my code.

```
$.ajax({
                            url: '../../search.do?param=searchUser',
                            type: 'post',
                            data:data,
                            success:function(result){
                                $("#dataTableBodyId").html(result);
                                $("#associatesDetailsId").DataTable({
                                    "responsive": true,
                                    "paging": true,
                                    "searching":true
                                });
                            },
                            error:function(){
                                alert("error");
                            }
                        });
```

Please help me.

Comment: You _must_ use the [**destroy: true**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy) option if you want to reinitialize the dataTable.

Comment: destroy is not working and if I put destroy:true then the changed output is not rendering on datatable, it is showing the old values and also if I put anything inside **$("#associatesDetailsId").DataTable({});** it is showing initialization error as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than fighting with the code you have, you need to re-engineer your approach. The basic problem as @davidkonrad mentioned is, you can not initialize the table more than once (pass the options to the constructor).

That is, this block of code, when executed the 2nd time, is leading to the error:

```
$("#associatesDetailsId").DataTable({
   "responsive": true,
   "paging": true,
   "searching":true
});
```

In your question you state that you have 3 input fields, if these are textboxes that the user type their search criteria into, then this example should get you started:

[Search example with individual text inputs](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html)

Notice only time the constructor is called (where the options could be passed) is at line #9.

```
// DataTable
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
```

After the table is initialized, `columns.every()` method is called and it is passed a function which itself initializes an event listener on the `keyup` event. The `every()` method assures the event listener is bound to every search input box.